# How to call Context.getSystemService(String) from JNI?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need to get the `WifiManager` in my JNI code. The twist is that I don't have access to any app-specific Java classes to implement it there. I only have `Context`. 
The problem is that I can't call `GetMethodID` successfully. Specifically, I think it's the signature that's the problem. I've tried

```
"(Ljava/Lang/String;)Landroid/net/wifi/WifiManager;"
```

and

```
"(Ljava/Lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;"
```

but neither have worked.

Here's my code:

```
jobject context = getContext();
jclass cls = jniEnv()->GetObjectClass(context);
jmethodID method = jniEnv()->GetMethodID(cls, "getSystemService", "(Ljava/Lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;"); // Fails
```

Comment: `GetMethodID(cls, "getConnectionInfo",` <-- I thought you said you were trying to get the id of the `getSystemService` method?

Comment: @Michael: oops, pasted the wrong line from the source. It was actually correct in the code.

Comment: Does your `getContext` function actually return an instance of `Context`? Or does it return an instance of some subclass of `Context` (e.g. `Activity` or `Application`)?

Comment: Also, how sure are you that `context` is actually a Context? Maybe log cls.className() to confirm which class object you have.

Comment: @Michael: good catch. It's passed from my `Application` subclass as `Native.setContext(this)`, where `setContext` is the native method that accepts `Context`. I have, however, tried `FindClass` instead of `GetObjectClass(context)`, to no avail...

Comment: Well, have you tried obtaining the method id on the result of calling `FindClass("android/content/Context")`, and then invoking the method through your `Application` instance with [`CallNonvirtualObjectMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp4581)?

Comment: @Michael: yes. Here's what I have right now: `env->GetMethodID(env->FindClass("android/content/Context"), "getSystemService", "(Ljava/Lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object");`

Comment: @Michael: `FindClass` succeeds, `GetMethodID` fails.

Comment: You've got a typo in your call to `GetMethodID`. `Ljava/Lang/String` should be `Ljava/lang/String`.

Comment: @Michael: Looks like it was that **plus** the missing ';' after `Object`. Post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, don't forget to convert arguments to java objects like this one:

```
jmethodID getWindowManager = env->GetMethodID (context, "getSystemService" , "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;");

// convert to java object
jstring serviceName = env->NewStringUTF("window");

jobject wm = env->CallObjectMethod(application, getWindowManager,serviceName);
```